# Using the fetch() method in database query to get an array

Tags: database

I have a very simple query that does the job, to get a collection of a specific content type's node id and title, that's it.

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$query = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'n');
$query->condition('n.type', 'employee');
$query->condition('n.status', 1);
$query->fields('n', ['nid', 'title']);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

And what i get is an array filled with objects (for each individual results) with two `properties` the nid and title values. But i want to have an single layer/dimension array filled with key => valued pairs (nid => title). Example bellow.

```
$results = [
  0 = {stdClass} (
     nid => 123,
     value => Susan Green
  )
];
```

And what i want:

```
$results = [
  123 => Susan Green,
  567 => Bob Young
];
```

I've tried fetchAllAssoc, fetchAssoc, etc but either the `result` is empty or i get something completely opposite of what i want.

Any ideas? **without using a parses to convert objects into what i want, that's what i'll do if none one can find an appropriate answer.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [fetchAllKeyed](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21StatementInterface.php/function/StatementInterface%3A%3AfetchAllKeyed/8.2.x) try with:

```
  $connection = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'n');
    $query->condition('n.type', 'employee');
    $query->condition('n.status', 1);
    $query->fields('n', ['nid', 'title']);
    // use fetchAllKeyed
    $results = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed(0,1);
```

Comment: Gives this person a cookie, you are correct, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome, i'm glad that help :)